# UseEffect infinite loop / runs forever even when state is not changed

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks, infinite-loop, use-effect

I am currently putting an API GET request call inside the useEffect. The idea here is to have 're-render' the list everytime the state is being modified.

```
const[superheroes, setSuperheroes] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        apiCall('/superheroes', { method: 'GET'})
        .then(response => {
            response.json().then(response => {
                setSuperheroes(response);
            }).catch(x=> console.log("ERROR: " + x))
        })
    }, [superheroes])
```

Simply doing this will result in an infinite call loop even when the `superheroes`state has not changed yet.

Can I get a clear explanation why is this happening?

EDIT: to clarify. I intentionally not using empty array as the second parameter of the useEffect() since I don't want to run it once.

Answer (score 0):

**This happens when you set a new array (also an object) in the useEffect**

```js
function DoSomethingCrazy() {
  const [superheroes, setSuperheroes] = React.useState([]);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("i have arrived at the party!");
    setSuperheroes(["123123"]);
  }, [superheroes]);

  return <div>stuff goes here</div>;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<DoSomethingCrazy />, rootElement);
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <div id="root"></div>
```

Try to put an empty array to the useEffect, so it only runs once:

```
useEffect(() => {
  apiCall("/superheroes", { method: "GET" }).then((response) => {
    response
      .json()
      .then((response) => {
        setSuperheroes(response);
      })
      .catch((x) => console.log("ERROR: " + x));
  });
}, []);
```

Comment: Yes I understand that. But what I want is to do an API call everytime the state is changed, hence I did not put the empty array

Comment: Then you would need to have another state. For separate of concerns. It’s not recommend to have one state does many things.

Answer (score 0):

The effect will be triggered every time superhero is changed. Because useEffect always execute the first time and then depending on the array of dependencies the code get in a situation where the ajax call is made and with the response the superheroes is change by setSuperheroes, then because is a dependency for useEffect, the whole process will happens again.

Here you are not re-rendering, you are just re-fetching by ajax.

Answer (score 0):

React use `shallow compare` to compare new state and current state.

When API call success, `setSuperheroes` will call with a new array and state will have a new value. With `shallow compare`, the new state always different from current state so component always re-render.